# Checking Firestore Collection element exist or not

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

I want to check the ***entered text (EditText)*** element is exist or not using Firestore Collection if Exists where exists or fetch the remain elements Note: **we don't have document id**

I want to mobile if our user collection the mobile exists then fetch the remain elements the document id will **Random using AutoID** and ignore Additional Collections like **Withdraw Requests**

[image: Details]
[image: Details]

I write this code in my activity

```
private void fetchDatafromFirestoreCollection() {

    firestore.collection("Users").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
            if (error != null) {
                if (dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();

                Log.e(TAG, "Error is: ", error);
                return;

            }
            for (DocumentChange documentChange : value.getDocumentChanges())
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Please Read Description to Understand What I'm trying to say

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What is the exact data you want to check for existence?

Comment: The question seems to be unclear. Can you describe  the question in detail and state clearly what you want to achieve?

Comment: @AlexMamo I want to to check in Users collection is Refferal "ABC123" exists if exists who is the user then i fetch the mobile or other details

Comment: I want to fetch all the documents to check where ABC123 exists or not to give him refferal amount

Comment: For eg: I want to who was entered the `ABC123` if user exists then fetch his details in a string to give him Reward like Modern apps where users enter some promo Code like **Hallowen50, Diwali100**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this comment:

> I want to to check in Users collection is ReferCode "ABC123" exists if exists who is the user then I fetch the mobile or other details

And this comment:

> I want to fetch all the documents to check where ABC123 exists or not to give him refferal amount.

To solve this, you have to use a query that looks like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference usersRef = db.collection("Users");
usersRef.whereEqualTo("ReferCode", "ABC123").get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    String mobile = document.getString("Mobile");
                    Log.d("TAG", mobile);

                    //Do what you need to do with the phone number
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
9876543210
```

Comment: how you reply with my comment is that any inbuilt feature of Stackoverflow of Manually Copy and paste the text

Comment: I only used `>` in front of your comments, that were added as copy/paste.

Comment: what will i do when someone enters the wrong `ReferCode` that was not exists in the database because i tried `addOnFailureLister` but that was not executed when enters the wrong code. ? ? ?

Comment: No, onFailure will be called only if Firebase servers reject the request. It will not be triggered if no documents will be returned

Comment: so what i used to check if no documents will be returned i want to set error in edit text by `binding.referEd.setError("Wrong refer code")`

Comment: Without seeing your entire code, I cannot be much of a help. So please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: I uploaded please check here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69944724/16204988?stw=2

Answer (score 0):

Make the document structure like this one:

```
    DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("Users").document("123456789");
                docRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(DocumentSnapshot snap, FirestoreException fe) {
                        if (snap.exists()) {
                            //exists
                        for (DocumentChange dc : snap.getDocumentChanges()) {
                            //Store exist information to your Object model.
                            UserInfo userinfo = dc.getDocument().toObject(UserInfo.class);
                         Log.e(TAG, "userinfo: "+userinfo.getCompany);
                        }
                        } else {
                            //not exists
                        }
                    }
    
                });
```

Hope its work..

Comment: i don't have the document id